# how three loops are getting executed

Tags: python

I have a problem with this line of code:

```
res = [[int(i) for i in sub] for i in test_list for sub in i]
```

When this line will execute `int(i)` will get 24 in the first iteration and then this 24 is converted into `[2,4]` as shown in the output listed below.
How 24 can get converted into `[2,4]` which is a list? To get converted into a list, numbers should be iterable, shouldn't they?

```
   test_list = [['24'], ['45'], ['78'], ['40']] 
   print("The original list : " + str(test_list)) 
   res = [[int(i) for i in sub] for i in test_list for sub in i] 
   print("The list after conversion : " + str(res))
```

Output is:

```
     The original list : [['24'], ['45'], ['78'], ['40']]
     The list after conversion : [[2, 4], [4, 5], [7, 8], [4, 0]]
```

Comment: When you have three loops inside a list comprehension your code will be clearer if you use normal for loops. When you iterate through a string you access one character at a time. So your for '24' your code is doing ```int(2)``` and then ```int(4)```.

Comment: That line is confusing due to the existence of two entirely unrelated variables named `i`.  Change either the first two or last two references to a different name, and what it is doing should be clearer.  `int(i)` is never being passed the value 24, the strings have been split into individual characters before that.

Comment: Using more meaningful variable names, your code would be: `res = [[int(letter) for letter in word] for item in test_list for word in item]` which is pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
res = [[int(i) for i in sub] for i in test_list for sub in i]
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
test_list = [['24'], ['45'], ['78'], ['40']]   
res = []
for i in test_list: #so, i is similar to ['24'] initially
    for sub in i: #so, sub would be similar to a string '24' initially
        temp = [int(i) for i in sub] #iterate through string 1 character at a time. convert to str.
        res.append(temp)
```

If you notice, i have deliberately left 1 list comprehension inside. It can be expanded further but with a caveat. The `i` variable does not refer to the `i` variable outside, because comprehensions come with their own scopes that do not leak.

The entire code would be equivalent to:

```
res = []
for i in test_list:
    for sub in i:
        temp = []
        for i_ in sub: #using i_ just to elaborate it is a different value 
            temp.append(int(i_))
        res.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4], [4, 5], [7, 8], [4, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a list comprehension, the output is a list. The input can be any iterable - here, you're using a string - but the output is always a list. So when you do

```
[int(i) for i in '24']
```

you're looking at

```
[int('2'), int('4')]
```

which resolves to

```
[2, 4]
```

---

If your goal is to get the integer values from this list:

```
test_list = [['24'], ['45'], ['78'], ['40']]
```

the better way to go about it is to have just one `for` loop / list comprehension, not three. No need to iterate through the inner "lists" - if they're only one element, you can just resolve that manually:

```
res = [int(num[0]) for num in test_list]  # num == ['24'], so num[0] == '24'
# res == [24, 45, 78, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in test_list` will iterate through the list and return you `['24'] -> ['45'] -> ['78'] -> ['40']`

`for sub in i` will iterate through these lists. Each of them contains only one element which will be returned.

`for i in sub` will iterate through strings and return each char: `'24': '2' -> '4'

so

`[int(i) for i in sub]` will return you such lists: `[[2, 4], [4, 5], [7, 8], [4, 0]]`

---

If you want a list of integers, you can use:

`res = [int(l[0]) for l in test_list]`

> `[24, 45, 78, 40]`